# Problema ao tentar abrir um Drawer Navigator aninhado dentro de outro Drawer Navigator - React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native, navigation-drawer

Tenho uma tela principal que contém dois drawers Navigators(um para navegar entre as telas e outro para aplicar um filtro na tela principal). Pois bem, cada tela possui um Header que contém os botões para abrir os drawers navigators, em cada tela passo a seguinte propriedade para o header que serve para abrir ao apertar um dos botões:

```
onPress={() => Navigation.dispatch(DrawerActions.openDrawer())}
```

Essa propriedade abre somente o DrawerNavigator que está mais aninhado, o que posso fazer para abrir o primeiro?

Answer (score 0):

Cada Header precisa estar inserido dentro de um Drawer diretamente. Caso esteja dentro de um Drawer que está dentro de outro, ele vai enxergar o último.